# Can Initial Conditions be integrated?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Suppose I'm given the initial condition:

$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} (\pi, y) = y^2
$$
Can this be integrated to the form:
$$
U(\pi, y) = \pi y^2 + c
$$
And if not, why is this? I can't see any issues with this immediately, and am even wondering if the $c$ can be removed.

Comment: The "integration constant" should be a function of $y$.

Comment: In general, if you know the derivative of a function at one point, what can you deduce about the value of function itself at that point?  Nothing at all.

Comment: @gedgar is spot on. Maybe simpler, ignore any $y$ dependence: What does $U’(\pi) = k$ tell you about the values of $U$?

Comment: No valuable answer without context of the problem.